# Repaint() is not workning out of run() function

Tags: java, applet, runnable, repaint

I'm trying to make a simple applet with java to show two counters.
To simplify the code i created a function named "suma" which is called 2 times in run(). The counters in the console works, but in the applet aren't increased. I thing the problem is in repaint(), because when i try to execute the content of "suma" in run directly the code works. 
The question is: Why repaint() don't works out of run()?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class HiloContador extends Applet implements Runnable{
    //Propiedades
    private Thread h1;
    private Thread h2;
    long contador1=0;
    long contador2=500;
    private Button b1,b2;

    public void start(){}

    public void init(){
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        //Botones
        add(b1=new Button("Parar hilo 1"));
        add(b2=new Button("Parar hilo 2"));
        //Creación de nuevos hilos y su inicio
        h1=new Thread(this);
        h2=new Thread(this);
        h1.start();
        h2.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        suma(h1,contador1);
        suma(h2,contador2);     
    }//fin de run

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString(Long.toString((long)contador1), 80, 100);
        g.drawString(Long.toString((long)contador2), 80, 120);
    }

    public void suma(Thread h,long c){
        Thread hiloActual=Thread.currentThread();
        while(h==hiloActual){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(c);
            c++;
            repaint();
        }//fin de while     
    }   
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I change the suma function.
But i don't know how can use AtomicLong in .drawString.
g.drawString(Long.toString((long)contador1), 80, 100);
How can i parse AtomicLong to String for drawString()?
Solved with: g.drawString(contador1.toString(), 80, 100);

Comment: Is that comment supposed to be addressed to Nicolas Filotto? If so, comment on the answer, not the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you provide a primitive type like a `long` to a method, you pass **its value** not its reference such that when you increment `c` in your method `suma` you don't actually modify the value of your variables, you just increment the provided value, use [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) instead of `long` as parameter of your method since **it will then be passed by reference** as it is no more a primitive type but an object reference, then increment its internal value with [`incrementAndGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet--) and get it with [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#get--).

**Your code would then be:**

```
...
AtomicLong contador1 = new AtomicLong();
AtomicLong contador2 = new AtomicLong(500);
...

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString(Long.toString(contador1.get()), 80, 100);
    g.drawString(Long.toString(contador2.get()), 80, 120);
}

public void suma(Thread h, AtomicLong c){
    ...
        System.out.println(c);
        c.incrementAndGet();
        repaint();
    ...
}
```

More details about [pass-by-reference/pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Yes. It works for me, but i used c.addAndGet(1) instead c.incrementAndGet(). Thaks.